# Material UI TextField Lable has not enough space

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to change the label font bigger.
However, the input frame won't be adjust with the bigger font label as the pic shows.
My code as the follosing:

```html
<div>
    <TextField 
    fullWidth
    label="Business Notes"
    id="Business Notes"
    multiline
    rows={8}
    inputProps={{style:{fontSize:15}}}
    InputLabelProps={{style:{fontSize:20}}}
    />
</div>
```

Any solusion?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyOK3.png)

Comment: Can you add the relevant code snippet please?

Comment: Change `inputProps` to `InputProps` (captial I) and set both fontSize to the same value and it'll be fixed.